# How to use JExample with @Rule instead of @RunWith

Tags: junit, junit4

I need to add dependencies between behavioural-test methods where I use @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) to run the tests.

I add Mockito to the mix by using:

```
@Rule
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = new MockitoRule();
```

Where MockitoRule is a short class implementing MethodRule applying Mokito behaviour, I managed to scrounge up somewhere.

Now the question: Anyone have ideas of how I would archive a somthing similar with JExample, ie: applaying it with a @Rule instead of using the @RunWith(JExample.class)?

Comment: I’m the author of JExample, please get in touch we me so we can work together to get JExample runnig with rules. My email is akuhn@iam.unibe.ch

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexample/) and [github](https://github.com/akuhn/jexample), it doesn't look like there has been much development in JExample in the last couple of years, so there probably isn't a `@Rule` for JExample. I would contact the original author to see how easy it would be to add a `TestRule`.

At first glance, it seems that it would require a slight change to how [JExample works](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/jexample), because the return values of the tests are actually used, whereas the base runners for JUnit assume that the methods are void return values.